# How to Get JSON String to Int then to Arg Bundle?

Tags: android, json, string, int, bundle

I'm trying to pass an Int value pulled from a JSON String to reduce code redundancy.

Within my JSON file, I have a string value in "*resFile*". I store this string into **TAG_RES_FILE** where I want to pass it in a Bundle as an Int.

If you look in my code, you will see comment *//TRY #1//*.  This works as expected but I need that **Int** to come from a variable that stores my **TAG_RES_FILE**. At comment *//TRY #2//*  is just an example to what I want to function - obviously it does not. In the next line, I tried converting the tag string to a **Int** but this gives a runtime error of:

> java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "resFile"

I have even tried putting 0x7f060000 (from R.java) into the JSON String.

So my question is: How do I accomplish this? Am I on the right track or should I go about it a completely different way?

Thnx for your help and input - please show code examples in your answer.

JSON String Snippit:

```
[
    {
        "_id": "1",
        "label": "A Lable",
        "title": "Some Title",
        "description": "Bla, bla, bla",
        "containerID": "Some container id",
        "isRawRes": "boolean value here",
        "resFile": "R.raw.advisory_circulators_sort_list"
    }, {. . .
]
```

In my HashMap:

```
// Parse the string to a JSON object
        for (int i = 0; i < json.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject json_data = json.getJSONObject(i);

            // Storing each json item in variable
            String id = json_data.getString(TAG_ID);
            String label = json_data.getString(TAG_LABEL);
            String title = json_data.getString(TAG_TITLE);
            String description = json_data.getString(TAG_DISCR);
            String containerID = json_data.getString(TAG_FRAG_ID);
            String isRawRes = json_data.getString(TAG_IS_RAW_RES);
            String resFile = json_data.getString(TAG_RES_FILE);

            // creating new HashMap
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

            // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
            map.put(TAG_ID, id);
            map.put(TAG_LABEL, label);
            map.put(TAG_TITLE, title);
            map.put(TAG_DISCR, description);
            map.put(TAG_FRAG_ID, containerID);
            map.put(TAG_IS_RAW_RES, isRawRes);
            map.put(TAG_RES_FILE, resFile);

            // adding HashList to ArrayList
            mList.add(map);
}
```

In my ListViews setOnItemClickListener:

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    . . .

        final Bundle args = new Bundle();

//TRY #1//int rawRes = R.raw.advisory_circulators_sort_list; <--I NEED TO GET THIS IN FROM MY TAG!!
//TRY #2//int rawRes = TAG_RES_FILE; <-- TO SOMETHING LIKE THIS!!
        int passResFile = Integer.parseInt(TAG_RES_FILE);//<--THIS GIVES A NPE!!
        args.putInt("KEY_RES_FILE", passResFile);

        bolean isRawRes = true;
        args.putBoolean("KEY_IS_RAW_RES", isRawRes);

        // Delayed to improve animations
        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                ListViewFragment lvf = new ListViewFragment();
                lcFT.replace(R.id.listContainer, lvf).commit();
                lvf.setArguments(args);
            }
        }, 300);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead, just store `advisory_circulators_sort_list` as opposed to `R.raw.advisory_circulators_sort_list`. Then, to get the Integer identifier, use this method:

```
int passResFile = getResources().getIdentifier( resFile, "raw", getPackageName() );
```

Comment: Could you take a look [over here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11003846/742030)? Its related to this Q.  Thnx